# A few questions on iOS sharing

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have developed an app that allows a user to add/create/store images on their iPhone or iPad.  What I want to add to this app is the ability to 'pass' those images to another user's iDevice.

So, for instance, let's say I made an image that is stored on my iPhone.  I then have 3 other people sitting at the table with me.  I want to send that information to them as they each have the app installed on their iPhone or iPad.

This capability should (as I envision it) work over bluetooth connections or over the network that all the devices are connected to.

So, my questions are as follows:

1. Is this possible?
2. If I do this, could it cause my app to be rejected in the App Store?
3. Can anyone tell me where I can go to get the information to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it's possible.
2. Nothing you described sounds like grounds for App Store rejection.
3. Look up [`GKSession` in the GameKit framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1).  It is your best friend when creating iOS device to iOS device bluetooth or local WiFi connections.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [Bump API](http://bu.mp/company/api) useful; it is indented exactly for this kind of in-the-same-place data sharing.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main way's you could do this;

1. Locally via bluetooth
2. Locally via Wi-Fi
3. Using a web service

As Jesse Rusak mentioned, Bump is a good option for local exchange. However if you don't want to be restricted to 3rd party API's you could also use Game Kit.

You could also build your own web service, an example of how to do this is from a wonderful blog post http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12.